# Is the ending of the anime and manga the same (ERASED)

Tags: erased

I was wondering, is the anime ending and the manga ending the same for `Boku dake ga Inai Machi`?
Or is there going to be a sequel for the anime version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is dramatically changed  as it is mentioned in [What are the differences between the manga and the anime adaptation and where does the anime diverge?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/30817/what-are-the-differences-between-the-manga-and-the-anime-adaptation-and-where-do)

**⚠ The answer below contains spoilers.**

> The end of the anime is dramatically changed. In the manga, the story follows a bit of a longer period of time after Satoru can walk. The ending takes place in a holiday camp for patients who undergo recover such as Satoru and Kumi. There, the death match takes place between Satoru and Yashiro and is more complex as compared to the anime. Sawada and Kenya having a bigger role as well.
>
> In the last showdown scene, Yashiro intends to kill Satoru and himself on a bridge set on fire. Satoru escapes and Kenya and Sawada save Yashiro's life, an event present only in the manga